# Remove some special characters from a string and convert to decimal a column of a data frame

Tags: r

I have a data frame with a column called "Revenue" its a char and its with this format "$34,391.92"  I need to remove the "$" and the "," characters, but keep the "." an turn it into a numeric type

I have tried to take it one by one using the `gsub` function but it replaces all the values with NA

```
data$Revenue <-as.numeric(gsub("$", "", data$Revenue))
```

Comment: `readr::parse_number("$34,391.92")`

Comment: `$` is a special token in regular expression. For searching the dollar char in a string you would need `\\$`. But anyway, regular expressions are an overkill for replacing the `$` char.

Comment: `as.numeric(gsub("\\$|\\,", "", "$34,391.92"))`. You were not subbing out the comma in your version.